# Appending word in certain lines by using a list with line numbers with SED

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file example.txt which contains multiple lines:

```
Larry is funny!
Funny, I've no glue!
Look here!
Tom has no pants.
The underpants are in the drawer.
Pants are in the closet!
```

After creating a file with 4 random line numbers

```
sed -n '=' example.txt | shuf | head -3 > line_numbers.txt
```

Assuming the line numbers in line_numbers.txt contains

```
1
3
6
```

I want to edit example.txt by appending the word WORD at each line from line_numbers.txt which contains the full word "pants" (not partial words like "underpants").

How can I do this?

I wish the example.txt looks like this

```
Larry is funny!
Funny, I've no glue!
Look here!
Tom has no pants.
The underpants are in the drawer.
Pants are in the closet!WORD
```

Edit:

to find only full words, you have to write your source_word like `\<source_word\>`.

Other possible example:

I have another file which contains these lines:

```
I love apples.
You hate pineapples.
Apple pie is delicious.
Why do you do not like eating an apple?
We prefer pears to apples.
How many apples do you want to eat?
I have to bake three apple pies for sunday.
```

I have a list with three random line numbers

```
6
2
4
```

I only want to add at the end each line `--OK`, if the line contains the full word `apples`.

The output must look like this:

```
I love apples.
You hate pineapples.
Apple pie is delicious.
Why do you do not like eating an apple?
We prefer pears to apples.
How many apples do you want to eat?--OK
I have to bake three apple pies for sunday.
```

Comment: It's unclear how you want to use the line numbers.  Appending something to each line that contains `pants` can be done with `sed '/pants/ s/$/WORD/'`.

Comment: I only want to append WORD on line 6 and not every line which containts the word "pants".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Please also add more details in what way it "*is not working*".

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: If the input line was `sweatpants are comfortable` and the line number was a match should WORD be added to the end of that line? i.e. do you want to match on partial words or only full words?

Comment: @EdMorton fully words.

Comment: OK - all of the answers posted so far, including the one you accepted, do partial word matches instead of full word and so will fail given the case I mentioned. You should update your sample input/output (or maybe more appropriately ask a new question) to cover that case and any others you can think of so we have something to test a potential solution against. With these sorts of questions it's always trivial to match the text you want but harder to not match similar text you don't want so it's very important when asking such a question to really THINK about the possible input.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the hint, that the word must be a full word, written in `\<word\>`. I will consider the possible input in my next questions.

Comment: Using `\<word\>` means you're thinking of this in terms of a regexp match instead of string (so you'll be OK with identifying and escaping any regexp metachars that occur in the "word"), and are OK with restricting yourself to GNU tools. There are other ways this could have been handled using portable string matching instead of GNU-specific regexp matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect there's a way in `sed` too, but personally I find `awk` much easier for this sort of more complex manipulation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} 
    { 
        s=tolower($0); 
        if(FNR in a && s~/pants/){$0=$0"WORD"}
    }1' line_numbers.txt examples.txt 
Larry is funny!
Funny, I've no glue!
Look here!
Tom has no pants.
The underpants are in the drawer.
Pants are in the closet!WORD
```

If you have GNU `awk` (`gawk`, the default on Linux systems), you can do this to edit the file in place:

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; print; next} 
                { 
                    s=tolower($0); 
                    if(FNR in a && s~/pants/){$0=$0"WORD"}
                }1' line_numbers.txt examples.txt
```

Or, slightly simpler if you don't mind losing the contents of `line_numbers.txt`:

```
gawk -i inplace 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} 
                { 
                    s=tolower($0); 
                    if(FNR in a && s~/pants/){$0=$0"WORD"}
                }1' line_numbers.txt examples.txt
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted! Thank you! Can I also combine this code with a sed line?

Comment: @RamónWilhelm see update for how to edit the original file, if that was what you meant.

Comment: The last two codes are exactly the same code. I receive awk: not an option: -i as output.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm they are _almost_ exactly the same code, there is an extra `print` in the first one: ` NR==FNR{a[$1]++; print; next} `. OK, if you get that error, you don't have GNU `awk` or you're not using it. WHat operating system are you on? Do you have `gawk`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu "18.04.5 LTS". gawk is installed, but my files line_numbers.txt examples.txt are now cleared. Update: Now it's working!

Comment: @RamónWilhelm yay!

Answer (score 3):

The following pipeline, which is a modification of yours, outputs a `sed` script that performs your edit:

```bsh
sed -n '=' file | shuf -n 3 | sed 's,$, { /\\<pants\\>/ s/$/WORD/; },'
```

Or, equivalently,

```bsh
awk '{ printf "%d { /\\<pants\\>/ s/$/WORD/; }\n", NR }' file | shuf -n 3
```

This could, for example, generate

```
6 { /\<pants\>/ s/$/WORD/; }
5 { /\<pants\>/ s/$/WORD/; }
1 { /\<pants\>/ s/$/WORD/; }
```

This script applies a substitution that adds `WORD` at the end of each line matching the pattern `pants`, if that pattern occurs on any of the randomly selected lines.

Running this is a matter of reading it with `sed -f`:

```bsh
sed -n '=' example.txt | shuf -n 3 | sed 's,$, { /\\<pants\\>/ s/$/WORD/; },' |
sed -i -f /dev/stdin example.txt
```

or, with my `awk`-based variant:

```bsh
awk '{ printf "%d { /\\<pants\\>/ s/$/WORD/; }\n", NR }' example.txt | shuf -n 3 |
sed -i -f /dev/stdin example.txt
```

No intermediate file is needed.

Replace `pants` with `apples` and `WORD` with `--OK` to address your updated query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a oneliner (albeit a little long!).

Assuming that your text file is "tfile" and the index file is ifile, then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0;p=0}{if(FNR==NR){a[i++]=$1} else {if(a[p]==FNR){p++;g="";if(index($0,"Pants")){g="WORD"};  print $0,g}else{print $0}}}' ifile tfile
```

and you will get:

```
Larry is funny! 
Funny, I've no glue!
Look here! 
Tom has no pants.
The underpants are in the drawer.
Pants are in the closet! WORD
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, we may construct sed code  from the line numbers file and apply them on the data file:

```
sed -f - <<\eof line_numbers.txt |\
sed -f - example.txt
  1i /pants/I!b
  s/$/ba/
  $a b;:a;s/$/WORD/
eof
```

---

Another method is where we transcribe a sed command per line number

```
sed -e 's:.*:&s/pants.*/\&WORD/I;t:' line_numbers.txt |
sed -f /dev/stdin example.txt
```